# Amazon RedShift Copy Command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am using the data found on this [page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-dev-t-load-sample-data.html) to practice the copy command.

But i am getting an exception

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: S3ServiceException:The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.,Status 301,Error PermanentRedirect,Rid 8D10A2C0B9C7570E,ExtRid VTQZsFdP8DRiJPza+Ko4bc2Y91P9Wra0Qb9C
  Detail: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  S3ServiceException:The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.,Status 301,Error PermanentRedirect,Rid 8D10A2C0B9C7570E,ExtRid VTQZsFdP8DRiJPza+Ko4bc2Y91P9Wra0Qb9C
  code:      8001
  context:   Listing bucket=awssampledb prefix=tickit/allusers_pipe.txt
  query:     576
  location:  s3_utility.cpp:525
  process:   padbmaster [pid=4283]
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The S3 bucket and redshift must be in the same region (US East):

> This example uses an Amazon S3 bucket that is located in the US East (Northern Virginia) region. When you load data using a COPY command, the bucket containing your data must be in the same region as your cluster.

If your redshift cluster is in another region, look at [Step 5: Load Sample Data from Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/gsg/rs-gsg-create-sample-db.html), scrolling to the table with *region-specific-bucket-name*:

```
------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Region                      |  region-specific-bucket-name  |
------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| US East (Northern Virginia) |  awssampledb                  |
------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| US West (Oregon)            |  awssampledbuswest2           |
------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| EU (Ireland)                |  awssampledbeuwest1           |
------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Asia Pacific (Singapore)    |  awssampledbapsoutheast1      |
------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Asia Pacific (Sydney)       |  awssampledbapsoutheast2      |
------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Asia Pacific (Tokyo)        |  awssampledbapnortheast1      |
------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the source region as below

```
copy pep.test 
(operation, task_id, task_name)
from 's3://move-redshift-data-devo/move-redshift-data-devo/'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::355750824903:role/RedshiftDynamoDBAccess'
format as csv
region as 'us-east-1';
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-source-s3.html#copy-region

Comment: Generic and an acceptable solution rather than restricting to the same region.

Answer (score -1):

The s3 bucket and Redshift should both be in the same region. If not, the Region option needs to be specified in the copy command, then the load will work fine.